# Mounting Old EBS Volume to the new Instance - Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

1) I had an instance and sudo commands were not working do to some mistakes on this instance 
so i had to create a new instance.

2) I want to use old EBS volume with new instance and to stop old instance.

3) I created a new instance (New EBS Volume is created automatically with new instance)

4) I created snapshot of old volume and attached with  new instance.

5) So two EBS volumes are attached with new instance.

6) When i login using SSH into new instance, i don't see old data anywhere.

7) I want every old data on new instance.

---

my question is.....
how i can use old volume with new instance?

please help me.. i am trying it from last 10 hours continuously :(..

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information to be able to answer this question. Was your previous instance a Micro instance, and if so, did you stop it, or did you terminate it? Was the old data on the EBS volume that was automatically created when you created your first instance, or on a separate EBS volume? Did you mount the old EBS volume on the new instance using `mount`? You can check by running `df` in an SSH shell. Can you show us the output of that `df` command?

Comment: 1) Yes both are micro instance of same zone, 2) I stopped old one, 3) It was on separate volume and 2nd instance also created a new volume but i attached both to the new instance, 4) I don't know how to mount old EBS volume to new instance but i have attached it through amazon control panel, 5) DF output is  Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952    961696   7211384  12% /
tmpfs                   305624         0    305624   0% /dev/shm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is mount the old volume on the new instance. Go to the Amazon EC2 control panel, and click "Volumes" (under Elastic Block Store). Look at the attachment information for the old EBS volume. This will be something like `<instance id> (<instance name>):/dev/sdg`

Make a note of the path given here, so that'd be /dev/sdg in the example above. Then use SSH and connect to your new instance, and type `mkdir /mnt/oldvolume` and then `mount /dev/sdg /mnt/oldvolume` (or whatever the path given in the control panel was). Your files should now be available under `/mnt/oldvolume`. If this does not solve your problem, please post again with the output of your `df` command after doing all of this.

So, to recap, to use an EBS volume on an instance, you need to attach it to that instance using the control panel (or API tools), and *then* mount it on the instance itself.

Comment: it is an exact solution... thanks daan :)   is there any quick way to use all apache, mysql configuration with new instance that is available in "/mnt/oldvolume"?    basically i want to run the server(apache,mysql) as they were running on old instance including all old configurations

Comment: yes, replace `httpd.conf` and `my.cnf` on your new volume (use `whereis httpd.conf` and `whereis my.cnf` to find them) with the ones from the old volume. if you want to use the data from the `www` and `mysql` directories on your old volume too, the easiest approach is to create symlinks like this: `rm -rf /var/www`, `ln -s /mnt/oldvolume/var/www /var/www`, `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`,`ln -s /mnt/oldvolume/var/lib/mysql /var/lib`

Note that this will remove any data you may have put in these directories on your new volume, so you may want to change this a bit, but this is the rough idea.

Comment: don't forget to execute `service httpd stop` and `service mysqld stop` before doing this, though - and then afterwards use `service httpd start` and `service mysqld start` to restart them with the new settings

Comment: very nice and accurate answer daan :) ... one more thing that why the command "ln -s" is used? is it used to move/copy from old volume to new volume? can we use "mv" instead?

Comment: you could use `mv` but that's different: `mv` would move the data from your old volume to the new one, but `ln -s` just creates a symlink (a shortcut) to the data on the old volume, so that detaching your old volume would also mean the new instance loses access to your data. it depends on your usage case which you want to do :)

Comment: I have a similar question.  In my case, I have two EBS volumes that show as attached, `i-e1b...:/dev/sdf`  and `i-e1b...:/dev/sda1`.  However when I do a `df` when logged into the instance, none of these show up.  When I try `mount /dev/sdf /mnt/oldvolume`, I get an error message, I get an error message `mount: special device /dev/sdf does not exist`  I'm a newbie with this, so any input would be helpful!

Comment: it's probably easier to figure out what's going wrong if you post this as a new question with some more details about your configuration :)

Comment: It turns out that `/dev/sdf` actually is mounted as `/dev/xvdf`.  See more info here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=194798

Comment: right - depending on your Linux distro :) glad you got that figured out!