# Mount amazon instance store to another instance - it is possible? how?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Due to system crash after update i set up new instance with ebs(old instance has an instance store). But i need to copy some data form old instance to new. It`s possible to mount instance store from old instance to new? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across this thread: [Mounting Old EBS Volume to the new Instance - Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350222/mounting-old-ebs-volume-to-the-new-instance-amazon-ec2)

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but the answer on that thread details the process of mounting the old EBS volume to the new one on an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunetly it does not work with instance store, it seems to only ebs could be mounted in another instance.